# Turn off all Bokeh Axis Objects

Tags: python, bokeh

What's the name of this extra Bokeh component (see red arrow below)? I am using Bokeh's gridplot layout to display several bar charts and using an empty cell to display a legend. I can't figure out how to turn off this last artifact, presumably because I don't know what it's called. I've looked through the docs, but wasn't able to pick it out.

Secondly, is there more succinct method to accomplish what I am doing? Bokeh doesn't appear to be able to render a legend as a stand alone object.

```
# Dummy plot for the legend
p = figure()
p1 = p.vbar(color='steelblue', width=0.3)
p2 = p.vbar(color='peru', width=0.3)

p1.visible = False
p2.visible = False

legend = Legend(items=[
    ("General",   [p1,]),
    ("HCA",   [p2,]),
    ], location=(0, -30))

p.add_layout(legend)
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.title = 'Mgt. Status'

p.axis.visible = False
p.grid.visible = False
p.outline_line_width = 0
plots.append(p)

grid = gridplot(plots, ncols=4, plot_width=200, plot_height=200)
show(grid)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Meet the same problem as you did.

This is my solution:

```
figup.axis.axis_label=None                      # turn off label
figup.axis.visible=True                         # turn on axis visibility

figup.axis.major_tick_line_color = None         # turn off axis major ticks
figup.axis.minor_tick_line_color = None         # turn off axis minor ticks
figup.axis.major_label_text_font_size = '0pt'   # turn off axis minor ticks label text
figup.axis.axis_line_color= "white"             # turn off axis by setiing it to white
```

I just make it white to sort of hide the axis.

Hope this helps.

[Result of the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B6aE.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is the axis line, e.g. [`axis_line_color`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/axes.html?highlight=rule#bokeh.models.axes.Axis.axis_line_color).

Comment: `p.axis.axis_line_color='red'` has no effect. Nor does `p.axis.axis_line_width=0`. So that doesn't seem to be it.

Comment: @tharen What Bokeh version do you have? Your example worked just fine for me, without having to modify or add anything. I can see that there are black borders around each plot - does your `body` or any other common wrapper element have black background? Or is it just in the exported result?

Comment: Bokeh 2.0.2, Python 3.6.9, both installed from conda; Windows 10. It is running in JupyterLab notebook. The black outline is the body of the notebook from the screen snip.

Comment: You can see `axis_line_color` functioning in this example in the docs: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#axes To say anything further would require a complete minimal reproducer that demonstrates it not working.